# Obfuscating xamarin android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, obfuscation

I'm trying to Obfuscate my Xamarin android app and I did it for the DLL was in the

output but when I click export android package in visual studio the DLL I protected was delete and the DLL without obfuscate replace it

How should I do it?

Comment: Obfuscation is pointless, I hope you know that.

Comment: Don't go for obfuscation.it will give nightmare.

Comment: I suggest you tu try this: http://www.babelfor.net , it's useful!

Answer (score 3):

Obfuscating of Xamarin Android apps doesn't make much sense (of course you can turn on "Enable ProGuard" option if you want) but you can turn on "Embed assemblies to native code" which will convert all code into a binary .so file.

Comment: there is many app that when you want to open them you can't see the code but about xamarin android its completely your source,, please help me to obfuscate the code

Comment: native is for ultimate users but i m enterprise user

Answer (score 2):

Here's [a blog post explaining how to obfuscate a Xamarin Android app with Dotfuscator](https://www.preemptive.com/blog/90-dotfuscator/xamarin-applications-and-dotfuscator/671). It says there's an issue around file locations after the obfuscation process:

> In order for the Xamarin platform specific build process to properly find the obfuscated assemblies, they have to be copied back into the original assembly locations after obfuscation. Android has an additional restriction in that the original obfuscated PCL must be copied back to its project specific location as well.